# Is this example sentence in the New Oxford American Dictionary wrong?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I found a maybe erroneous example sentence under the entry "shuffle" in the New Oxford American Dictionary(3rd Edition):

> a change of order or relative positions; a reshuffle: 
>   the president will deliver a speech short on economic details Cabinet shuffles but long on fight.

You may also find it online: http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O999-shuffle.html

I think "economic details Cabinet shuffles" in this sentence is not only just awkward but also definitely wrong. It hardly makes any sense.

And about "long on fight" at the end of the sentence, I also think it's doubtful in meaning.

What do you say?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because may be the result an issue arising from obtaining corrupt information from a web-site that performs poor fidelity plagiarism of printed dictionaries, and not a genuine English language problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an erroneously-transcribed sentence

Comment: I read the paper dictionary first and then found the sentence weird. As a foreigner, I did confused and I searched online and unfortunately, there's no much results and I didn't find the very sentence on Oxford website. So I asked the question. I hope you would understand. For my part, it had been a turely pure language question when I asked——only turned out to find it's a wrong sentence.

Comment: It is on the page 1620 of New Oxford American Dictionary(Third Edition).

Comment: RE: _I asked the question. I hope you would understand._ Just to reassure you, I think the community does understand. It's a fair question. In and of themselves, closed questions are neither a form of censure nor a form of censor, which is why you don't lose any rep points when a question is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.  It doesn't make any sense.

It appears that the example sentence in the NOAD has been edited down from [this original sentence from the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1992/08/20/news/under-the-dome-news-analysis-bush-in-a-truman-mode.html):

> Unless there is Herculean last-minute rewriting, *the President will deliver a speech on Thursday night short on economic details **and** Cabinet shuffles but long on fight*, like Truman's speech in the stifling Philadelphia heat 44 years ago, with its brassy promise to "win this election and make those Republicans like it."

The key difference is the word ***and***.  Without it, I'm unable to understand the sentence.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing "and", and this complete original sentence. I indeed misinterpreted that "economic details Cabinet shuffles" part.

Answer (score 3):

***"Short on"*** and ***"long on"*** are idioms.

*"Short on"* means *having too little of one thing and a lot of another*. [ref](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/short+on)

*"Long on"* means *having a lot of one quality and not enough of another*. [ref](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/long+on)

The sentence can be read like this,

> The president will deliver (a speech) (short on economic details [and] Cabinet shuffles) but (long on fight).

<sup>For the discussion on this missing *"and"*, see @snailboat's answer.</sup>

As it appears, the president seems to prefer to talk about the fight, rather than the economic details [and] Cabinet shuffles.

Comment: Thank you. But still, What is "fight" then? Does it refer to "war" and go without the definite article "the"? Can "economic details Cabinet shuffles" be right whereas it can be phrased as "the economic details of Cabinet shuffling" or something else?

Comment: To be sure, we will need the context. It can be interpreted as either "going to war" or "fighting an economic crisis". Without any specific context, I feel the latter is more likely.